# Elementary Proof that $x^x \geq x!$

Tags: inequality

Is there an elementary proof that $x^x \geq x!$ for natural numbers $x$? I am not looking for a heuristic argument such as the one that there are $x$ terms in $x^x$ and $x!$ and since almost every term in $x \times x \times .... \times x$ is greater than almost every term in $x(x-1)(x-2)...(1)$, then $x^x \geq x!$

Comment: Nothing wrong with that argument! If you prefer, one can write that argument out more formally as an induction.

Comment: x is real or integer?

Comment: I was only looking to find a proof for the natural numbers. How would one go about proving it for all real numbers?

Comment: It's not true for real numbers (where you interpret $x!$ as $\Gamma(x+1)$).  For $0 < x < 1$, $x^x < \Gamma(x+1)$.

Comment: You used x and you haven't stated clearly that x is a natural number. For natural numbers, I think it can be easily proved by induction.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For $n=1$ is valid.
$$1!\leq 1^1$$
Assume for $n$ is valid:
$$n!\leq n^n$$

Multiply by $n+1$ both sides

$$(n+1)!\leq n^n(n+1)\leq(n+1)^n(n+1)=(n+1)^{n+1}$$

The last step is because if $n\leq n+1$ then $n^n\leq (n+1)^n$

Comment: I like this proof by induction. Thank you!

Comment: @VarunGudibanda no problem!

Answer (score 5):

**Hint:**  Prove  that $\ln \, x^x \geq \ln x!$ (for $x\geq 0.$)

**Edit**  Since $\ln x \geq \ln i,$ for $i \leq x,$ we have 
$$
\ln x+\ln x +\cdots \text{ ($x$  times total)}+\ldots \geq \ln 1 +\cdots \ln x,
$$
or $$x \ln x \geq \sum_{i=1}^x \ln i=\ln x!.$$

Comment: $xln(x) \geq \sum_{i=0}^{x-1}ln(x-i)$ and this means that
$x \geq 1 + \sum_{i=1}^{x-2}\frac{ln(x-i)}{ln(x)}$ Where would I go from there?

Comment: $x \ln x \geq \sum\limits_{x=0}^x \ln x$

Comment: I'm still not able to see where I would proceed from here. Would I try to divide both sides by $ln(x)$?

Comment: I added the explanation.

Comment: Ah ok. It seems obvious now that I see the solution. Thank you very much!

Comment: What is the point of taking the logarithm?

Answer (score 4):

I really wouldn't call the argument you mention "heuristic." Simply note that
$$\dfrac{n^n}{n!}=\frac{n}{n} \frac{n}{n-1} \frac{n}{n-2}\cdots \frac{n}{2} \frac{n}{1}\geq 1$$
This is because every term in the product is larger than or equal to 1.